# Type error with internationalization feature of sails.js based on i18n

Tags: internationalization, sails.js

I'm trying to use the internationalization feature of [sails](http://sailsjs.org) based on i18n.

In my controller it works well. However, I would like to setup this in my model definition.

Please see the code below:

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
name:{
  type:'string',
  required:true,
  displayName: sails.__("test")
  },
   ....
```

Unfortunately it does not work. I have the error below:

```
   displayName: sails.__("test")
                     ^
  TypeError: Object [a Sails app] has no method '__'
```

Would you have an idea?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> `displayName: sails.__("test")`

You are trying to invoke the internationalization function *statically*; that is, you're seeing the error because you're running that function the moment your `.js` file is `require()`d by node.js, and before `sails` has finished loading.

There are two ways you can go about solving this problem.

#### 1. Translate the value on each query

If you'd like to store the original value of `displayName`, and instead internationalize it each time you query for the model, you can override [`toJSON()`](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/records/toJSON.html).

> Instead of writing custom code for every controller action that uses a particular model (including the "out of the box" blueprints), you can manipulate outgoing records by simply overriding the default toJSON function in your model.

For example:

```
  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string',
      required:true,
    },
    getDisplayName: function () {
      return sails.__(this.name);
    },
    toJSON: function () {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      obj.displayName = sails.__(this.name);
      return obj;
    },
    ...
  }
```

#### 2. Translate the value before create

You can use the [**Waterline Lifecycle Callbacks**](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html) to translate the value to a particular language before the model is saved to the databas

> Sails exposes a handful of lifecycle callbacks on models that are called automatically before or after certain actions. For example, we sometimes use lifecycle callbacks for automatically encrypting a password before creating or updating an Account model.

```
  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string',
      required:true,
    },
    displayName: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    ...
  },
  beforeCreate: function (model, next) {
    model.displayName = sails.__(model.name);
    next();
  }
```

This internationalized the value of `displayName` will now be set on your model before it is inserted into the database.

Let me know how this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is interesting. However, my wish would be to have a display name for each properties.

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
name:{
type:'string',
required:true,
displayName: "Your great name"
},
 adress:{
type:'string',
required:true,
displayName: "Where do you live?"
},
```

....

So is there a simple or clean solution to apply sails.__( foreach properties display name of the attribute?

Thanks,